# Elasticsearch mapping parameters : index vs enabled

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping

I've been struggling with two elasticsearch mapping parameters: `index` and `enabled`. I'm using Elasticsearch 6.2.4.

---

Here's my case.

**Mapping**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "user_id": {
          "type":  "keyword"
        },
        "last_updated": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "session_data_index_false": { 
          "index" : false,
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "session_data_enabled_false": { 
          "enabled" : false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Indexing**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "user_id": "jpountz",
  "session_data_index_false": "hello", 
  "session_data_enabled_false": "hello", 
  "last_updated": "2015-12-06T18:22:13"
}
```

**Search1**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "session_data_index_false": "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

I got 400 error with following message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"match\" : {\n    \"session_data_index_false\" : {\n      \"query\" : \"hello\",\n      \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n      \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n      \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n      \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n      \"lenient\" : false,\n      \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n      \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n      \"boost\" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
        "index_uuid": "6ByxNrjIRQmF23zcmKOvUA",
        "index": "my_index"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "my_index",
        "node": "DYPnEJWjTtm58oxZ9F-RSg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"match\" : {\n    \"session_data_index_false\" : {\n      \"query\" : \"hello\",\n      \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n      \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n      \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n      \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n      \"lenient\" : false,\n      \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n      \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n      \"boost\" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid": "6ByxNrjIRQmF23zcmKOvUA",
          "index": "my_index",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot search on field [session_data_index_false] since it is not indexed."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
```

**Search2**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "session_data_enabled_false": "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, I didn't get any error. Instead, I got following result, meaning that none of documents was found.

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

**Retrieval**

```
GET my_index/_doc/1
```

Of course, I could retrieve original data.

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "user_id": "jpountz",
    "session_data_index_false": "hello",
    "session_data_enabled_false": "hello",
    "last_updated": "2015-12-06T18:22:13"
  }
}
```

---

I read official documents on above options.

- [enabled option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html)
- [index option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html)

And also, I've read [this article](http://queirozf.com/entries/what-do-store-index-all-source-mean-in-elasticsearch) but found out that it was compatible with elasticsearch 1.5.

Is anyone here aware of how those two options differ from each other?

Thanks in advance.

Best

Comment: Do you expect the query on `session_data_index_false` to not error out and simply return no documents instead?

Comment: @Val Nope. I just want to grasp the difference between two options. Based on official documents, index and enabeld are options to use when I want to diable indexing for specific field value. But not sure when to use each option and why one is raising an error while one is not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When settings `enabled` to false, you tell ES to completely ignore the parsing of the field, so it will neither be analyzed, nor indexed not stored (except in he `_source` field of course).

So, ES is not even aware that the field exists, and thus, it handles that case as if you were querying on any other non-existent field, basically as if the source didn't even contain the field. Result: ES doesn't return any document.

When setting `index` to false, ES is aware that the field exists (via the mapping), but it knows that it shouldn't be indexed. So when you query on it, ES tells you that you cannot do it since you've decided not to index that field. That's why ES throws an error since you're breaking the contract that you've declared in your mapping.

Comment: Oh, I see it's clear enough. Thanks for prompt and appropriate answer.